# Where does the other end of the line lead?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "Where does the other end of the line lead?" mean "to what place does the other end of the line lead to?"

> New York Times tweeted just now:
> Every year, tens of millions of Americans collectively lose billions of dollars to scam callers. **Where does the other end of the line lead?**

Comment: A line leads somewhere, the other end of a line _is_ somewhere. Must have been a hasty tweet. These messages are often written using poor grammar.

Comment: Thanks. Please make it pretty grammatical if you would like to. We have space here, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often find poor or hasty use of language in tweets, text messages, etc. The writer probably meant 'What (or who) is at the other end of the line?'. The 'line' here is clearly the telephone line or connection that exists between a called person and a scam caller. Possibly the writer wished to combine this thought with 'What will speaking to the person at the other end of the line lead to?'